# Visual Studio 2008 crashes when displaying XAML view. How to get more information?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, logging, crash

I am developing a Silverlight app using VS2008 Express. I have just implemented a new user control and have added it to a Grid.

When I try to open a XAML view which contains this control, VS crashes and restarts.

Where can I look for more information? Is there an event log in VS?

**Update** I found my problem which was a circular reference causing a ... Stackoverflow. The logs didn't help much - I had to read through the code in another editor and search for my bug.

Comment: Before anything I would confirm I am running the later service pack and hotfixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, look in the windows event log (app log). It will probably show a fastfail error message along the lines "*NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3053 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (7A035E00) (80131506)".*"

To get more details on what caused it you can either attach another VS instance as a debugger and watch the debug output, or you can enable [fusion logging](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx) since this is usually caused by assembly load errors.

One common cause of VS fastfails is a bug in .net 2.0 SP2 that is described in more detail here:
http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=963676

Other workarounds (if the patch described in the MSKB article linked to above don't work) are:

1) Running "ngen /delete *" (with administrative privileges, from the .net framework 2.0 directory).

2) An add-in I wrote that loads all referenced assemblies (and allows you to tweak the load order) whenever opening a project instead of as-needed. You can get it (and the source code for it) from here:
http://www.huagati.com/ProjectLoader/download/HuagatiProjectLoader.zip

Comment: Just noticed that you're using VS Express - that rules out using the last workaround (the add-in) since VS Express don't support add-ins. But the other two (the mskb patch, and "ngen /delete *" works fine with VS Express).